# Is it safe to use the same key for different variants of the HMAC-SHA algorithm?

Tags: hash, hmac, key-size, key-reuse

I need to apply HMAC-SHA hashes in my application. Depending on the context I'll use either HMAC-SHA512, HMAC-SHA256 or HMAC-SHA1.

Is it safe to use the same key for all of these algorithms, or do I need to use a different key for each hash type? I plan to make the key 128 bytes which I understand is long enough for all of them.

Comment: Why not simply use a single algorithm?

Comment: Well some of the data being hashed is guaranteed to be very short (around 120 bytes) so using a hash that is longer than the data seems wasteful.

Comment: How about choosing one of these functions and truncating the output?

Comment: Reducing the security level for shorter messages seems a bit dubious. Assuming you need a MAC/PRF and not a collision resistant hash, you could use 128 bit MACs for everything.

Comment: Well I was planning to use full HMACSHA512 for messages that are cycled through user's web-browser because I consider it high risk. Was planning to use a shorter/truncated hash for the shorter message that will be stored in a secure database to reduce the risk of tampering. But I'll take your advice and user the longer hash for everything.

Comment: @AndySkirrow: Are you getting bits and bytes mixed up?  SHA-512 output is 512 **bits**, which is 64 bytes, shorter than the 120 byte data you mention. By the same token, a 128 byte key (1024 bits!) seems excessive.

Comment: @AndySkirrow: And another question you may want to ask yourself is whether you can somehow make your keys [ephemeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_key).

Comment: @Luis Well this is the length of key my implementation (.NET) generates automatically

Comment: 1024 bits is probably the length for HMAC-SHA512? It does not help to use a shorter key since they get padded to that length anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the answer to your question is that while it is recommended that you never reuse keys for different algorithms, it is quite unlikely that different hashes in HMAC would interact badly.

However, that does not mean what you are planning is the way to go. It makes little sense to change the strength of the authentication based on the length of the message, unless the message length directly correlates with the security level you expect. And even if that is something you want, there is no real advantage to using different HMAC hashes.

Instead, you should pick either SHA-256 or SHA-512 and use only that hash for HMAC. You *can* truncate the authentication tag to the desired length, which can vary with message length. However, you must make sure an attacker cannot simply use a shorter tag in all situations. And it is not really required, since even a 64-bit tag is usually considered sufficient. So you should likely just pick one length you are comfortable with.

Oh, and a 128-byte key is overkill. 256 bits is sufficient.